# Generalize getter

Tags: c#, generics, getter

I have a lot of properties in my code where I have to get their value from resources. So I've a lot of

```
private string _labelText;
public string LabelText
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_labelText))
            _labelText = GetFromResources(Constants.LabelText);

        return _labelText;
    }
}
```

How can I generalize this code in order to not repeat it every time.
Best have is return different types.

Thank you.

Comment: [Write a snippet.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Didn't you see the code I wrote?

Comment: Blue is a beautiful color. It's lovely code, except for the missing curly braces. You can write snippets to automate the creation of code like that. I recommend it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: that's not elegant: if you decide at one place to change the code, you have to update all getters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Fair enough. But if you've got that many of them, even if you write something like the (excellent) answers below, you'll either be copy/pasting them and forgetting to change stuff sometimes, or else creating them with a snippet. It's still Mad Libs code, and snippets are well suited to producing it.

Comment: If you want to reduce repeating code to minimum - use PostSharp (or alanog AOP framework).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public string LabelText => Get<string>(Constants.LabelText);

private T Get<T>(string resource)
{
    object value;
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(resource, out value))
        value = _cache[resource] = GetFromResources(resource);
    return (T)value;
}
```

Then you can create multiple of those one-liner properties as needed.

Comment: If all/most of the resource names are equal to the property name then it would be a nice option to add CallerMemberName attribute and reduce the one-liner to public string LabelText => Get<string>();

Answer (score 1):

An idea might be to scope the logic of the resource loading into a method:

```
private static T LoadResource<T>(ref T cache,string name) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cache)) {
            cache = (T) GetFromResources(name);
    }
    return cache;
}
```

Then you can write your getters like:

```
private string _labelText;
public string LabelText {
    get {
        return LoadResource<string>(ref _labelText,Constants.LabelText);
    }
}
```

By using `ref` you reference a field, and thus can access/modify/... that field in other parts of the code.